# A continuous function on compact space

Tags: functions, continuity, compactness

If a function is said to be continuous on a compact subspace of real numbers, it means that the function is continuous on a closed interval as in $[a,b]$ right??

Or does it make sense to say continuous on a finite set or infinite countable set?

Comment: There are compact sets in $\mathbb R$ which are neither intervals nor countable. See, for example, the Cantor set. Also, it does make sense to talk about, say, continuity on the countable compact set $\{0,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots\}$. It is true that continuity on a finite subset of $\mathbb R$ is essentially trivial - all such functions are continuous.

Comment: So it makes sense to talk about continuity on Cantor set also??

Comment: Sure. It makes sense to talk about continuity on *any* subset, compact or not, of $\mathbb R$. But some are more interesting than others. Restricting to compact subsets still leaves a lot more than closed intervals.